# SendPingAsync Reply return 11050

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ping

i'm trying make a simple ping application using SendPingAsync. But, pingReply.Status.ToString() return weird number "11050" when connection disconnected. It will return unsuccessful message like "TimedOut" or "DestinationHostUnreachable", but after some seconds. What does it means?

Here is my code :

```
async Task ngeping(String host, CancellationToken ct)
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    IPAddress ipaddress;
    PingReply pingReply = null;
    long tripTime;
    while (true)
    {
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        tripTime = -1;
        try
        {
            pingReply = await ping.SendPingAsync(host, 3000);
            ipaddress = pingReply.Address;
            if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                tripTime = pingReply.RoundtripTime;
                if(tripTime<300)
                    gaweRTF.insertLine(GaweRTF.HIGHLIGHT_GREEN, ipaddress.ToString() + " - " + tripTime + " ms");
                else if (tripTime < 500)
                    gaweRTF.insertLine(GaweRTF.HIGHLIGHT_YELLOW, ipaddress.ToString() + " - " + tripTime + " ms");
                else
                    gaweRTF.insertLine(GaweRTF.HIGHLIGHT_RED, ipaddress.ToString() + " - " + tripTime + " ms");
            }
            else
                gaweRTF.insertLine(GaweRTF.HIGHLIGHT_RED, "not success: "+pingReply.Status.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            gaweRTF.insertLine(GaweRTF.HIGHLIGHT_RED, ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        rtb.Rtf = gaweRTF.finishRTF();
        if (tripTime>=0 && tripTime<1000) await Task.Delay(1000 - (int) tripTime);
        if (pingReply.Status != IPStatus.Success) await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Edit : Here my application screenshots :

[Right after disconnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2kJr.png)

[After 10-15 "11050" message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk5cW.png)

Comment: Are you sure it's `11050`? Are you sure it's not `110005`?

Comment: Yeah, i add screenshots. The pingReply.Status.ToString() is 11050. Also, if the message "110005", what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buddy
this code : 11050 means General Failure

Request failed for an unknown reason.

For more information, see Knowledge Base article 325487, "How to troubleshoot network connectivity problems" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=3052&kbid=325487).

Comment: This answer relies almost completely on the content of external links. Should they ever become invalid, your answer would be useless. So please [edit] your answer and add at least a summary of what can be found there. Thank you!

Comment: This is C++ version, but shows the list of the codes - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ipexport/ns-ipexport-icmp_echo_reply32